# Move a mesh on a line Three JS

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I have 2 Mesh. I want fire a projectile from the first mesh to the second.

For that i draw a line between them. But I'm not able to translate a projectile on this "line". I tried with the translateOnAxis function but it didn't work.

Do you know a method to move an object following a line ? 
Have you another methods ?

Thank You ,

Thomas

Answer (score 2):

So lets say you have object1 (of type `THREE.Object3D()`) and that you have done something like:

```
object1.position.set( 1, 2, 3 );
var position2 = new THREE.Vector3( 11, 12, 13 );
```

and you want object1 to move to position2.

You can include the tween.js library and do a tween between the two:

```
setupObjectPositionTween( object1, object1.position.clone(), position2,
    2000, 100, TWEEN.Easing.Linear.None );      // duration, delay, easing
```

using:

```
function setupObjectPositionTween( object, source, target, duration, delay, easing )
{
    new TWEEN.Tween( source )
        .to( target, duration )
        .delay( l_delay )
        .easing( l_easing )
        .onUpdate( function() { object.position.copy( source ); } )
        .start();
}
```

**EDIT:**

You would need to add in the animation loop:

```
TWEEN.update ();
```

and in the init():

```
TWEEN.removeAll();  // clear out tween buffer
```

Comment: Thank you , is my bad, i saw this library when i researched that on the web but i didn't think this library was made for that. Thank you very much.

Comment: TWEEN.removeAll() is important and often forgotten +1;